# link c files in vscode in linux show mistake : cc1: error: output filename specified twice

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio-code

this is my launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/pc",
    "configurations": []
}
```

this is my task.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cpp 生成活动文件",
            "command": "/usr/bin/cpp",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}/*.c", //这里是我修改的位置，修改后便提示如题所述的错误
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-lpthread"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "调试器生成的任务。"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

In the args of the task, I changed "${file}" to "${workspaceFolder}/*. c", and tried to use the command line to include all c files under the folder

In the launch, I added the setting option of "program" according to the guidance file, but I don't understand what it is for

Unable to use IDE due to course requirements

In addition, it should be mentioned that the code will disappear and display as two lines of address after the code reports an error (too low reputation to send a picture)

Comment: what reads `launch.json` and `task.json`?

Comment: " it should be mentioned that the code will disappear and display as two lines of address" can you not copy-paste this text into the question directly?  We really do hate screenshots of text here at SO

Comment: I want to modify the configuration file and let the vscode under Linux c files within the folder link together

Comment: I haven't solved this problem, but I have found an alternative, which is to use the code runner plug-in and change its running settings to achieve the role of makefile.